# conda command disappear after an interrupted attempt to update conda base

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have been using conda for a long time, and now tried to update the base, as I always get warning when update packages. But use the command 'conda update -n base conda' resulted me errors, complaining that the setuptools can't be removed. So I use `conda update --force conda` to update it. However, everything goes well until at the `Executing transaction:` step, I lost my connection to the server. Actually the message is as below:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | Bad packet length 3374759699.
```

After I login in again to the server, I have no `conda` command anymore. Not in the miniconda3/bin! Just can't find the conda command. Other commands from the base environment still work, and environments' files are still there. My .bashrc file is the same as well (I mean I can't really tell the difference, as the path are still correct).

I really don't know how to solve this problem, as I need the `conda` command to activate other environments. Could anyone help please? I didn't find solutions by googling.

Comment: You can likely repair the **base** environment with `micromamba`, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918), but installing `conda` into the **base**.

Comment: Thanks @merv for replying me! I tried to install micro mamba, but seems like my `curl` also breaks due to the conda. It complains that it can't find the libssl, though it's in the lib directory of the base environment

Comment: Maybe don't activate the environment. Or use wget or some other means of downloading the installer. More install options [in the docs](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#manual-installation).