# conda installed an older, unusable version of mamba and I can't update it

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mamba

### The issue

I have Anaconda on two separate Windows PCs. On both, I installed mamba with

```
conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge
```

on one, it worked and it installed mamba 1.3.1. On the other, it installed mamba 0.1.0, which doesn't work - e.g. if I try
conda update pandas
I get an error about "no module named conda._vendor.auxlib" which, searching online, I understand was an error of older, unstable versions of mamba.

### What I have tried

`conda update mamba` tells me all requested packages are already installed

`mamba update mamba` doesn't work (no module named etc etc)

`conda install mamba=1.3.1 -n base -c conda-forge` to force the installation of version 1.3.1, doesn't work: it fails with initial frozen solve, retries with flexible solve, but after more than 3 hours it still did nothing

I then tried the other 3 subfolders of condaforge mentioned here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mamba (without really understanding the difference) but none worked - the command was processed without errors but mamba was not updated, as if no version > 0.1.0 existed

I also tried `'conda update conda-build'` which was mentioned here as a solution https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1583 but it didn't work

### What I have searched

This bug report mentions an issue similar to mine https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1583; most posters (but not all) managed to fix updating conda-build. This solution didn't work for me

Comment: You can use Micromamba to operate on broken base environments. I.e., it won't take 3 hours to figure out your solve issue. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918 Rather than an exact version, specify a minimum so that it will continue to update in the future (e.g., `micromamba install -n base 'mamba>=1.3'`). But generally, Mamba and Conda Forge simply are not intended to work with Anaconda **base**.

Comment: Would you consider accept some answers to you questions?  It is this gamifiication of this website that makes it fun, in my honest opinion.