# Conda is returning a Traceback error with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm' at the end every time I try typing anything with 'conda' in it

Tags: pip, conda, traceback, modulenotfounderror, tqdm

Any time I try doing anything with conda, even just typing the word conda, I get this error message:

```
MyName-2:~ Me$ conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 101, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .common.io import dashlist, timeout
  File "/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tqdm import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

How can I fix conda so that it doesn't keep doing this?

I have installed and even uninstalled and reinstalled tqdm countless times and it says it is there. This is what I get when I try installing:

```
pip install tqdm
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.65.0)
```

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` is a python installation different than your anaconda one. It looks to me like you have broken your base environment (since you are missing `conda` dependencies). The easiest and cleanest option might be a reinstall. In the future: avoid changing packages in `base` - apart from updating. Instead, create virtual environment with `conda` for your different projects

Comment: Alternatively, you can trying repairing with Micromamba (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918), but reinstalling `tqdm` or even `conda`). Consider removing non-Conda Python installations, since they can interfere with Conda (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918)).