# Python broken in miniconda3 base

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda

I have been using properly conda and the base environment in my server until I tried to install Visual Studio Code. When I set it up, I (arguably) tried to install it in the base environment by downloading the python extension and the jupyter extension. This gave me an error but I skipped it and I tried to install VS Code in another environment (and it worked).

When I came back to the main terminal, when I launched `conda activate ...` it gave me the following error:

```
-bash: /home/miniconda3/bin/conda: /home/miniconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: File or directory not existing
```

So I tried several things:

1. I checked if 'conda' was available in the bin:

```
cat /home/miniconda3/bin/conda.
```

And  there was
2) I checked if python was available in the bin:

```
/home/miniconda3/bin/python.
```

And there wasn't.

Checking with ls the bin environment I found that python was corrupted - displayed as red color with black background. Something similar to this example:

```
ls /home/miniconda3/bin
```

[image]

So, I tried to remove python and replace it with an existing python of another environment, but it still figured as 'corrupted'

In summary, python seems to have gone and, worse, I do not understand from where the error comes from.

Comment: Vscode itself is just a code editor. The problem may be caused by the choice of interpreter. Could you please use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the conda environment then retry?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that the installation of VS Code destroys your conda environment. Did you look at the official VS Code document [Running Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)? VS Code should be **independent** of your Python or Conda environment.

If you are on a Ubuntu Linux server, try downloading the VS Code from [VS Code Download Page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). Then simply run

```bash
sudo apt install ./the-file-you-downloaded.deb
```

Do you have a specific reason to install VS Code in the Conda base environment?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I run the installation of VS code directly from the app, installed in my personal PC by connecting to the server. The problem is not to have not the VS running, it is running actually on a different environement in the server. The problem is that durin its installation python seems to have broken.

Comment: Are you saying that you launched VS Code from your laptop, and used ssh to connect to the server? In this way, the VS Code is not running from the server. The Python's problem is not because of VS Code. Maybe try reinstall the miniconda, and see if the Python runs well through a command line. Then try connecting with your VS Code again and see if the problem still exists.