# Trouble with any conda commands, even deleting conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

Trying to update/generally run conda. Basically any command I type returns the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: <72A9D87B-A79B-31EA-9993-E99A1361DE6E> /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/anaconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Python API call failed', /var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_e2pplk40z3/croot/cryptography_1689373680118/_build_env/.cargo.Darwin/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-0.18.3/src/err/mod.rs:790:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1114, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 86, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 88, in do_call
        module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .install import install
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 18, in <module>
        from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .subdir_data import SubdirData, make_feature_record
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 53, in <module>
        from conda_content_trust.common import (
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_content_trust/common.py", line 63, in <module>
        import cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519 as ed25519
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519.py", line 9, in <module>
        from cryptography.exceptions import UnsupportedAlgorithm, _Reasons
      File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
    pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
```

I am also unable to install the anaconda-clean package.

I think this may have to do with conflicting python dependencies on my M1 machine. Additionally, anaconda3 is installed in the Applications folder rather than my home directory -- not sure if that is problematic.

Comment: Is this a new install? or is this is a change in behavior? Micromamba is useful for repairing broken **base** environments. Try reinstalling `libffi` in **base**.

Comment: does the user you're executing this as have write access to /Applications/anaconda3?

Comment: @MS yes I do have write access

Comment: @merv Not a new install, but a change in behavior. Haven't used conda in a while so just went to update and got this error. I get the same error when I try `conda install libffi --force-reinstall`

Comment: check `/Applications/anaconda3/lib` - does libffi.7.dylib exist? if not, create a soft-link from any existing libffi.?.dylib

Refer [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9957) 

HTH

Comment: Your Conda is broken, hence you need to use something like Micromamba to fix it. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918